# Replacing "Unmatched" with value from other row - under condition

Tags: dataset

I have

```
ds = Dataset@*
Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Date", "A"} -> #] &]@{{"C12", 
SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 11, 0, 0, 0.}], 10}, {"C12", 
SQLDateTime[{2015, 2, 19, 19, 30, 0.}], 9},
{"C12", SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0.}], 12}, {"C10", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 28, 9, 25, 0.}], 15}, {"C10", 
SQLDateTime[{2014, 3, 21, 20, 0, 0.}], 12}, {"C11", 
SQLDateTime[{2014, 8, 27, 6, 40, 0.}], 8}}
```

and

```
ds2 = Dataset@*
Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Date", "B"} -> #] &]@{{"C10", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 28, 0, 25, 0.}], 315},
{"C12", SQLDateTime[{2012, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0.}], 10}}
```

I combine them via

```
ds3 = SortBy["ID"]@JoinAcross[ds, ds2, {"ID", "Date"}, "Outer"]
```

[image]

Now, I replace the `Missing["Unmatched"]` values B by the values from the lines above.

```
Module[{prev = Missing["Unmatched"]}, 
rfunc[Missing["Unmatched"]] := prev;
rfunc[b_] := prev = b;
ds3[All, {"B" -> rfunc}]]
```

But I have the problem, that I only want to do this in case, the ID is the same as in the line above (line with  same ID but value for B existing). This means in line 4 (ID == C11) I'd like to have still an "Unmatched" instead of the 315, since the row above is corresponding to ID C10 instead of C11.

[image]

I would be very happy, if anybody could give me a hint. All I could think about so far didn't work and I have to present my data tomorrow ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an ugly approach i use sometimes ...

(and I reuse your rfunc idea)

```
rf[True, Missing["Unmatched"]] := prev;
rf[_, b_] := prev = b;

previd = "";
prev = -999;
ds3[All, (<|#, val = rf[#ID == previd, #B]; previd = #ID; 
    "B" -> val|>) &]
```

[image]

Or try this not much more satisfying approach (the idea is to extract/work on the column then replace it in the dataset) :

```
foo[b_, Missing["Unmatched"]] := b;
foo[_, c_] := c;

ds3[All, {"ID", "B"}] // Values // Normal // 
      GroupBy[#, First -> Last, FoldList[foo]] & // Values // 
    Flatten // Map[<|"B" -> #|> &, #] & // 
  Join @@@ Transpose[{Normal@ds3, #}] & // Dataset
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm actually trying to implement your solution and will edit this comment, asap.

Comment: The first solution works for me, the second I'll try after my talk this afternoon or maybe only in the new year. But this answer safed my day!

Comment: You're welcome. Also I modified the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function `lookup` to look up the `B` value from `ds2` via the `ID` key:

```
lookup[x_] := Query[SelectFirst[#ID == x &], "B"]@ds2
```

then replace the missing values,

```
SortBy["ID"]@ds3[All, <|#,"B" -> Replace[#B, Missing["Unmatched"] -> lookup[#ID]]|> &]
```

or just lookup the `B` value in all rows of `ds3` from `ds2`,

```
SortBy["ID"]@ds3[All, <|#, "B" -> lookup[#ID]|> &]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a new idea which helps. But I have a further problem, since for my real datasets the `SelectFirst` in the query does not work any time. Sometimes I have more than one case per ID - some with A missing, some with B missing. Maybe you have a further idea?